# Sed not working inside bash script

Tags: bash, sed, shell

I believe this may be a simple question, but I've looked everywhere and tried some workarounds, but I still haven't solved the problem.

Problem description:
I have to replace a character inside a file and I can do it easily using the command line:

```
sed -e 's/pattern1/pattern2/g' full_path_to_file/file
```

But when I use the same line inside a bash script I can't seem to be able to replace it, and I don't get an error message, just the file contents without the substitution.

```
#!/bin/sh

VAR1="patter1"
VAR2="patter2"

VAR3="full_path_to_file"

sed -e 's/${VAR1}/${VAR2}/g' ${VAR3}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: sed -e does not change the file, just show the file with the substution, but the file does not get changed, in either case

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try

```
sed -e "s/${VAR1}/${VAR2}/g" ${VAR3}
```

[Bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Double-Quotes) says:

> The characters ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes

Thus it will be able to resolve your variables

Comment: Great answer. And if you want to preserve newlines, go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114517/bash-how-to-preserve-newline-in-sed-command-output

Comment: Great answer! all other answer for this subject failed.

Answer (score 1):

I use a script like yours... and mine works as well!

```
#!/bin/sh

var1='pattern1'
var2='pattern2'

sed -i "s&$var1&$var2&g" *.html
```

See that, mine use "-i"... and the seperator character "&" I use is different as yours.
The separator character "&" can be used any other character that DOES NOT HAVE AT PATTERN.

You can use:

```
sed -i "s#$var1#$var2#g" *.html

sed -i "s@$var1@$var2@g" *.html
```

...

If my pattern is: "test@email.com" of course you must use a seperator different like "#", "%"... ok?