# Bash - how to preserve newline in sed command output?

Tags: bash, sed, echo, delimiter, cat

Assuming I have a file BookDB.txt which stores data in the following format :

```
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince:J.K Rowling:40.30:10:50
The little Red Riding Hood:Dan Lin:40.80:20:10
Harry Potter - The Phoniex:J.K Rowling:50.00:30:20
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow:Dan Lin:55.00:33:790
Little Prince:The Prince:15.00:188:9
Lord of The Ring:Johnny Dept:56.80:100:38
Three Little Pig:Andrew Lim:89.10:290:189
All About Linux:Ubuntu Team:76.00:44:144
Catch Me If You Can:Mary Ann:23.60:6:2
Python for dummies:Jared Loo:15.99:1:10
```

I am trying to replace the (:) delimiter with (, ) in my output. It succeeds, but removes the newline from the output. Here is my code :

```
TITLE=Potter
OUTPUT=$(cat BookDB.txt | grep $TITLE)
OUTPUT1=$(sed 's/:/, /g' <<< $OUTPUT)
echo $OUTPUT1
```

I want my output to look like this :

```
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince, J.K Rowling, 40.30, 10, 50
Harry Potter - The Phoniex, J.K Rowling. 50.00. 30. 20
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow, Dan Lin, 55.00, 33, 790
```

However, it looks like this :

```
 Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince, J.K Rowling, 40.30, 10, 50 Harry Potter - The Phoniex, J.K Rowling, 50.00, 30, 20 Harry Potter - The Deathly Holl
ow, Dan Lin, 55.00, 33, 790
```

If anyone could share how to preserve the line break in the output, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use correct quotation :

```
TITLE=Potter
OUTPUT=$(cat BookDB.txt | grep $TITLE)
OUTPUT1=$(sed 's/:/, /g' <<< "$OUTPUT")
echo "$OUTPUT1"
```

As `\n` is part of the default value of [IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator), it is removed without the double quotes.

More info on quoting [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html)

Comment: +1 but of course you could refactor it substantially to just `sed -n "/$TITLE/s/:/, /gp" BookDB.txt`

Comment: @tripleee Indeed. As anubhava already pointed this out, I just highlighted the quoting problem (that might cause more issues later in OP's code)

Comment: How could I achieve the same while expanding variable ? I need double quotes for expansion and single ones for keeping new lines...

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid `cat` and do all in sed:

```
sed -n '/Potter/s/:/, /gp' file
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince, J.K Rowling, 40.30, 10, 50
Harry Potter - The Phoniex, J.K Rowling, 50.00, 30, 20
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow, Dan Lin, 55.00, 33, 790
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`. Matching would be specific to the titles and doesn't include the author's name.

```
awk -F: -v OFS=', ' '$1 ~ /Potter/ { $1 = $1; print }' file
```

Output:

```
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince, J.K Rowling, 40.30, 10, 50
Harry Potter - The Phoniex, J.K Rowling, 50.00, 30, 20
Harry Potter - The Deathly Hollow, Dan Lin, 55.00, 33, 790
```

This gives no output:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=', ' '$1 ~ /Rowling/ { $1 = $1; print }' file
```

But this will:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=', ' '$2 ~ /Rowling/ { $1 = $1; print }' file
```

Output:

```
Harry Potter - The Half Blood Prince, J.K Rowling, 40.30, 10, 50
Harry Potter - The Phoniex, J.K Rowling, 50.00, 30, 20
```

To match against both title and author you can have:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=', ' '$1 ~ /Potter/ && $2 ~ /Rowling/ { $1 = $1; print }' file
```

Or to match if any validates:

```
awk -F: -v OFS=', ' '$1 ~ /Potter/, $2 ~ /Rowling/ { $1 = $1; print }' file
```